# why does image become pixelated? pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm curious to know how and why when I hover over the potato that it slightly becomes ever so more pixelated until it reaches a 16x16 pixel potato image? I don't really know where to begin with an explanation myself.

main.py

```py
import pygame
import math
import random
from potato import Potato
knife = pygame.image.load("knife.png")
knife = pygame.transform.rotate(knife, 270)
knife = pygame.transform.scale(knife, (200, 200))
potato = pygame.image.load("potato.png")
potato = pygame.transform.scale(potato, (200, 160))
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 500
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))


def main():
    done = False
    potatoThing = Potato(knife, potato, WIDTH/2-100, HEIGHT/2 - 80)
    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
        mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        window.fill((195, 245, 98))
        potatoThing.draw(window)
        potatoThing.update(mousex, mousey)
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()

main()
```

potato.py

```py
import pygame
import math
import random
from pygame.math import Vector2 as vect

def distanceBecauseMeep(min, max, value):
    if value < min:
        return min
    elif value > max:
        return max
    else:
        return value

class Potato:
    def __init__(self, sprite1, sprite2, x, y):
        self.knifeSprite = sprite1
        self.potatoSprite = sprite2
        self.pos = vect(x, y)
        self.isHoveringOver = False
        self.sizeOfPotato = (200, 160)
        self.sizeOfKnife = (200, 200)
    def draw(self, win):
        if self.isHoveringOver:

            self.sizeOfPotato = (220, 180)
            self.sizeOfKnife = (220, 220)

        else:

            self.sizeOfPotato = (200, 160)
            self.sizeOfKnife = (200, 200)

        self.potatoSprite = pygame.transform.scale(self.potatoSprite, self.sizeOfPotato)
        self.knifeSprite = pygame.transform.scale(self.knifeSprite, self.sizeOfKnife)

        win.blit(self.potatoSprite, (self.pos))
        win.blit(self.knifeSprite, (self.pos))
    def update(self, xPos, yPos):
        self.x = xPos
        self.y = yPos

        self.CosX = distanceBecauseMeep(self.pos.x, self.pos.x + self.sizeOfPotato[0], self.x)
        self.CosY = distanceBecauseMeep(self.pos.y, self.pos.y + self.sizeOfPotato[1], self.y)

        self.distance = math.sqrt((self.CosX - self.x)**2 + (self.CosY - self.y)**2)
        if self.distance <= 0.0:
            self.isHoveringOver = True
        else:
            self.isHoveringOver = False
```

here are some pictures to help show my point and confusion

when you first start the program:

[image]

when you hover over it a couple times

[image]

it could have something to do with the Tuples in potato.py but I'm not quite sure. I am really confused and didn't even know this was a possibility for images to become pixelated.

ive tried

```py
pygame.transform.smoothscale
```

but all that does is blur the image instead of pixelate the image

Comment: @RandomDavis ive tried ```pygame.transform.smoothscale``` all it does is instead of making it pixelated just makes it blury

Comment: Have you ever tried repeatedly downscaling and upscaling an image in an actual image editing program? What happens? Why?

Comment: it was because i was repeatedly scaling the same image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're repeatedly scaling the same image to different sizes and replacing the original with it.  Each time that's a lossy operation; instead, keep the **pristine** version and scale it to each desired size.  (With just two sizes, you might do this for each size ahead of time rather than doing it once every frame.)